# flex xml appendchild

Tags: xml, flex3, air

In my flex project I am using XML to populate TextFlow using:

```
TextFilter.importToFlow(XML(str), TextFilter.PLAIN_TEXT_FORMAT);
```

I woud like to add html links to the textflow. For that I adding html a tag in xml but I am getting parser error(malformed xml).

```
var fixed:String;
fixed = fixed.replace(link, "<a href='event:xyz' >"+link+"</a>");

XML:
<TextFlow xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/textLayout/2008"/>
added link as <a href='event:xyz' >link</a>
</TextFlow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your TextFilter.PLAIN_TEXT_FORMAT to TextFilter.TEXT_LAYOUT_FORMAT.